# Fiddler fails after CONNECT to HTTPS service

Tags: fiddler

Fiddler is unable to connect to my https server and is failing in the CONNECT stage itself. Firefox opens the site just fine. Here [1] is a screenshot of the requests. I tried with Charles and it was able to list the request but failed to decrypt the requests [2].

Please note that other HTTPS services seem to be working fine with fiddler

1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vit3Y.jpg

2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BnYZ.jpg

Comment: More details are needed. Did you trust the Fiddler HTTPS certificate? What is the client application? What do you see on the Log tab?

Comment: Yes, the certificates were installed. Also, traffic from other applications are showing up in Fiddler. This is one of our internal applications developed in QT.

Comment: I am using the latest fiddler(v4.4.3.0 beta). Here's the log dump from the requests. http://pastebin.com/7bL3zmfH

Comment: The error message is coming from your application, which is returning a TLS Fatal Alert upon receiving Fiddler's interception certificate. Either QT has its own certificate store, or it doesn't like makecert-generated certificates for some reason. Try 1. Disable HTTPS decryption in Fiddler and click Remove Certificates. 2. Install http://www.fiddler2.com/dl/FiddlerCertMaker.exe 3. Restart Fiddler. 4. Reenable HTTPS decryption. Do you get the same error message in the LOG tab?

Comment: I did as you said. The same error messages appear: `10:09:35:4534 !SecureClientPipeDirect failed: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. < An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate on pipe 16`

Answer (score 32):

Tools/Options/HTTPS ... Change TLS1.0 to TLS1.2 worked for me ...

[image]

Comment: This fixed it for me.  But why?

Comment: If server require min TLS1.2 then you have to use it.
If this helped to you, you could vote for question and answer.

Answer (score 4):

I did add Fiddler root certificate in IE and Firefox. Still I was getting this .....
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException A call to SSPI failed The function requested is not supported fiddler

I solved this by adding tls1.2 & tls1.2 under Tools--> Fiddler Options --> HTTPS (Tab) --> Enabled Protocols, and Fiddler started capturing https traffic from browsers.

Comment: Adding tls1.1 / 1.2 also helps if the Fiddler Composer requests fail and the browsers' requests work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with all SSL sites. It seems to happen when there are a lot of certs in the following folder C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates

stopping fiddler, emptying the folder and starting it up again fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Fiddler was randomly failing to do HTTPS CONNECT to `ajax.googleapis.com`, even though it works fine without Fiddler.  I tried this solution, restarted Fiddler, and it fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me:

Tools -> Fiddler Options -> HTTPS -> Reset All Certificates

Then I got prompted to create a new Fiddler certificate and trust it via windows.

Answer (score -1):

Try run Fiddler as Administrator. This is what works for me.